# How to store switch value when user come to controller

Tags: swift

I have one customized cell having one label and switch and I want to store the value of that switch which is on or off when user come to that controller.

```
var point = Int()
func cellButtonTapped(sender: UISwitch) {
    let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
    let cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
    print(cellIndexPath)
    point = cellIndexPath!.row
    print(point)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "setting"
    let cell =  (self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)) as? SettingCell
    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
     let str = options1[indexPath.row]
        cell?.label.text=str
        cell?.delegate=self
        return cell!
    }
    else if(indexPath.section==1){
        let str = options1[indexPath.row]
        cell?.label.text=str
        cell?.delegate=self
        return cell!
    }
    return UITableViewCell();
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(section==0)
    {
        return options1.count;
    }
    else{
        return options2.count;
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2;
}
```

Ccustomized cell:

```
protocol MyInfo {
    func cellButtonTapped(sender: UISwitch)
}
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate:MyInfo?

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.cellButtonTapped(self.switchButton)
        //print("hiii")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var switchButton: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please make a better title and format your code?

Comment: i just want to reatin the state of switch which is in customized cell using nsuserdefault

Comment: I fixed the title and format the code. Please edit again if you find a title more appropriate. Feel free to add a bit more of details to explain what exactly your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a target to your `UISwitch` like this for example

```
switch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("stateChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

where `stateChanged` is the name of the method that will be called with the event is triggered (When the `UISwitch` value changes). Then you need to add the actual `stateChanged` method which will save the value in `NSUserDefaults`

```
func stateChanged(switch: UISwitch) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(switch.on, forKey: "settings")
    //The key could be another string.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cellIdentifier = "setting"
let cell =  (self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)) as? SettingCell

 // bla bla cell customization
 cell.YourSwitchIn_SettingCell.tag = indexPath.row
return cell!
}
```

In your action for `UISwitch`

```
func cellButtonTapped(sender: UISwitch) {
//Access switch with tag
if sender.tag == 0 {
   let cell = addPostTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as! SettingCell
}

// Do What ever you want to do with cell.
let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
     let cellIndexPath =    self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
    print(cellIndexPath)
    point = cellIndexPath!.row
    print(point)
```

}